# can an android application check the version of the phone

Tags: android

I would like to write an application that uses live wallpapers for insatnce. this feature is supported only in version 7 and up. Is it posiible, that the application checks the version of the android phone and depending on that runs different code (e.g. uses live wallpaper or static background.)

Do you have a code example for that? Does that require special permissions?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're requiring Android 1.6 or newer:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Look at the [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class in Android. You can use it like so `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

Comment: RELEASE is not a good one, that's a user-defined string and could be anything (especially when you're using a custom ROM). SDK_INT is the way to go when you want to test for specific SDK features.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int ECLAIR_MR1 =7;
public static final int FROYO =8;

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==FROYO){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Iam a FROYO-Phone", 1).show();
}else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==ECLAIR_MR1){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Iam an ECLAIR-Phone", 1).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SDK_INT is not available on very early builds. So if your manifest has for instance:

```
android:minSdkVersion="1"
```

you can use something like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
static boolean getPreHoneyComb() {
    try {
        Build.VERSION.class.getField("SDK_INT");
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return true;
    }
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}
```