# Any way programatically to check the version of android platform

Tags: android

Is there any programatically way for my android application to know which version of android platform (1.6 or 2.0 or 2.3) that it is currently running on?

Thank you.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186948/can-an-android-application-check-the-version-of-the-phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build Class is easy to use : [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

```
if(Integer.decode(Build.VERSION.SDK) >=8) {
// shiny APIS 
 } else  {
    // old APIS
 }
```

check the excellent presentation by Reto Meier and the Parallel Activity pattern :
[here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twmuBbC_oB8)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to test for Froyo, pretty self explanatory for other versions

For below API level 4:

```
           int b = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
            Log.i(TAG, "SDK: "+b);
```

For above API lvl 4:

```
            int b = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            Log.i(TAG, "SDK: "+b);
```

Version:

```
           if(b == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
                Log.i(TAG, "Found Froyo");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK) to compare with the various [flavours](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)